# How do i tell my UIView that the button in UIViewController has been pressed? (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to pass data between the `UIViewController` and the `UIView`?
if yes, how?
I can not find anything on the internet which explains it.

For example when you press button1 the `UIViewController` says to the `UIView` that the person has pressed button1 and then the `UIView` draws a Circle. But if you then press `button2` the `UIViewController` says to the UIView that he has now pressed `button2` and then the `UIView` eliminates the Circle and draws a triangle.

The buttons are built programmatically.

The question is how I can invoke the shapes which I have drawn with `drawRect` within the `UIView` in the `UIViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 
   @IBOutlet var UnitViewTabeller: UnitView!
   var btn: UIButton!

   override viewDidLoad {
     self.btn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0.04 * view.bounds.width, 0.91 * view.bounds.height, 0.44 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height))  //set frame
            self.btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            self.btn.setTitle("0", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            self.btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            self.btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.2745, green: 0.2784, blue: 0.2706, alpha: 1.0) //set button background color
            self.btn.tag = 0 // set button tag
            self.btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btn) //add button in view
            self.btnArray.append(btw)
   }

   func btnclicked(sender: UIButton) {
       //draw the Circle from the UIView
   }


}    
    class CircleView: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let Circle = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0.2 * bounds.width, y: 0.15 * bounds.height, width: 0.6 * bounds.width, height: 0.6 * bounds.width)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(Circle, 4.0)
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(Circle, rectangle)
        CGContextStrokePath(Circle)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example in Swift 3 of a `ShapeView` that redraws itself when its `shape` property is set:

```
class ShapeView: UIView {
    var shape: Shape = .blank {
        didSet {
            // calling setNeedsDisplay() triggers a redraw of ShapeView
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    enum Shape {
        case circle
        case triangle
        case blank
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        switch shape {
        case .circle: drawCircle()
        case .triangle: drawTriangle()
        default: break
        }
    }

    func drawCircle() {
        let circle = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0.2 * bounds.width, y: 0.15 * bounds.height, width: 0.6 * bounds.width, height: 0.6 * bounds.width)
        circle?.setLineWidth(4.0)
        circle!.addEllipse(in: rectangle)
        circle!.strokePath()
    }

    func drawTriangle() {
        // code to draw a triangle
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a `ShapeView` object called `shapeView` as a property of your `ViewController`, you'd call it like this:

```
func drawCircleButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    shapeView.shape = .circle
}

func drawTriangleButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    shapeView.shape = .triangle
}
```